# How to select Element with empty class using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to select the element with  `class=""` like

```
<li class="" > </li>
```

I used

```
Elements topProductSecNav = topNavWrapper.select("li[class=]");
```

but I got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: String must not be empty` exception.

Answer (score 3):

Use this: `Elements topProductSecNav=topNavWrapper.select(li[class=\"\"]");`
See working example [here](http://try.jsoup.org/~-YhJ4BTUaAS89PhdB6zi1ZBIA1U).

Answer (score 1):

I would use the regex css selector `li[class~=^$]`:

```
String html= "<li class=\"\" > </li>"
           + "<li class= > </li>"
           + "<li class > </li>"
           + "<li > </li>"
           + "<li class=\"test\" > </li>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html,"");

Elements liWithClassButNoName = doc.select("li[class~=^$]");

for (Element li:liWithClassButNoName){
    System.out.println("li = "+ li);
}
```

results in this output (only the first 3 lis match):

```
li = <li class=""> </li>
li = <li class> </li>
li = <li class> </li>
```

Explanation:

`~=` means regex and
`^$` searches for an empty string

Jsoup will delete the `=` in the second example li element `<li class= >`. The regular expression also matches aparently a non existing string, so if you need to filter these out you may want to go with the solution given by @TDG.