# JSoup Extract title from img class

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm building a web scraper using JSoup. I'm attempting to extract the title out of img class from the below HTML code.

```
<div id="insideScroll" class="grid slider desktop-view">
    <ul class="ng-scope" ng-if="2 === selectedCategoryId">
      <li class="" data-list-item="">
          <span>
              <a class="grid-col--subnav ng-isolate-scope" data-internal-referrer-link="hub nav" data-link-name="hub nav daughter" data-click-id="hub nav 2" href="/recipes/111/appetizers-and-snacks/beans-and-peas/?internalSource=hub nav&referringId=76&referringContentType=recipe hub&linkName=hub nav daughter&clickId=hub nav 2" target="_self">
                  <img class="" alt="Bean and Pea Appetizers" title="Bean and Pea Appetizers" src="http://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/140x140/00/60/91/609167.jpg">
                  <span class="category-title">Bean and Pea Appetizers</span>
              </a>
         </span>
     </li>
</div>
```

Here is a function of what I have but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm receiving a Null Pointer Exception when I run it, which from the stack trace I'm assuming is due to the lack of a name in the image class. I could extract the title from the span class also, but am also having trouble getting the text from it. Thank you for your help.

```
@Override
public ArrayList<String> parseDocForTitles(Document doc) {
    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
    String title;

    Element insideScroll = doc.getElementById("insideScroll");
    Elements img = insideScroll.select("img.\"\"");

    for(Element ttle : img){
        title = ttle.attr("title");
        out.println(title); //just for testing
        titles.add(title);
    }

    return titles;
}
```

Below is the stack trace I'm receiving:

```
[-]ERROR: See Stack Trace
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Scraper.Appetizers.parseDocForTitles(Appetizers.java:35)
    at Scraper.Driver.main(Driver.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: Can you post the error please!

Comment: I posted the stack trace

Comment: Since I can't reproduce this error there is a chance that you are not parsing what you expect. If some parts of that HTML structure are generated by browser (with help of JavaScript) then it most likely will not be part of HTML response send to you from server which you are parsing. Try to print `doc` and see what you are really getting from server and if there is `<div id="insideScroll"...>` element. If there isn't `Element insideScroll = doc.getElementById("insideScroll");` assigns `null` to `insideScroll`. In next line `insideScroll.select` would be same as `null.select` which gives NPE.

Comment: This theory seems to be confirmed by fact that you are not seeing `IllegalArgumentException: String must not be empty` exception caused by `select("img.\"\"")`. If you want to select element with empty class take a look at this question: [How to select Element with empty class using Jsoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516650/how-to-select-element-with-empty-class-using-jsoup)

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

```
Document document; 
try { //Get Document object after parsing the html from given url. 
    document = Jsoup.connect(yourURL).get();   
    //Get images from document object. 
    Elements images = document.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");   
    //Iterate images and print image attributes. 
    for (Element image : images) { 
        System.out.println("Image Source: " + image.attr("title"));
    }   
} catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to select the img Elements correctly.

Change this:

```
Elements img = insideScroll.select("img.\"\"");
```

To this:

```
Elements img = insideScroll.select("img");
```

And it should work.

Comment: I'm still receiving the Null Pointer Exception. It says the exception is thrown from this line `Elements img = insideScroll.select("img");`

Comment: Then it must be coming from a different piece of your code. I was able to run that method with the html provided and it got the title of the img. Which line exactly is generating the Null Pointer?

Comment: The stack trace says line 35 which is `Elements img = insideScroll.select("img");`

Comment: Okay if that is throwing the Null Pointer, that means that the `Element insideScroll = doc.getElementById("insideScroll");` is the piece that is null.